# MVC 3 jquery renderbody <=> Header(_layout)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, header

So this is my issue:
I have in my MVC 3 project my layout with all my js script included:

```
<link runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/favicone/favicon.ico")" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link runat="server" rel="icon" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/favicone/favicon.ico")" type="image/ico"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dimension.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/globalize.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cultures/globalize.culture." + CurriculumVitae.Helpers.CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture() + ".js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {....}</script>
```

But only my default View can used these scripts, when I go in another view(in renderbody) and I need to use some jquery I need to RE-IMPLEMENT the script to make it work:

```
@{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
@section header{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                show: "blind",
                hide: "explode"
            });
            $("#opener").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                return false;
            });
        });
 </script>
}

<a id="opener" href="javascript:void();">test </a>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic modal dialog">
    <p>terst nmsdfnms dfds fsd f JQUERYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</p>
</div>
```

And this is just the beginning ... I have other issue with my Theme/Culture..

The thing is in the source code of my web page, I found all the scripts from the _layout (and the "view") but without the @section header, even a simple js call would not work if it has to used a script from my header(_layout)

thank you

Comment: Can you show us more of the _Layout file? Since you are using a section named "header" I would like to see where in the layout you implement that section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem:

1. Never re-implement or overide jquery-1.7.1.min.js within the same web
   page as it will create a conflict between each jquery call.
2. One of my scripts using (jcarousel.js) was not correctly setup (the
   initCallback param).

Thank you everyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you are not specifying a layout in your view there are two things you could try.

Ensure that your "default" layout is properly configured within `"~Views/_ViewStart.cshtml"`:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Of you could explicitly set the desired layout your view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: I think you don't need to set this parameter with MVC 3 and the @razor view engine.

I tried to force this setting as you suggest but it still didn't work.

Comment: They only time you don't need to make a layout reference is if you have a _ViewStart layout setup. However, if you explicitly set the layout view that contains your scripts and it is not appearing within your view then have an issue with how your project is structured. How are your views structured in your project and where are they located?

Comment: My _ViewStart layout is setup to diplay my _Layout View for all Views (inside the renderBody() ).
the thing is I can see my _layout when I navigate in my mvc application (I see my menu, footer, <header></header>,...) And this is where I am lost because If I ask my browser to show me the source code, It will find everything (js, css files) but It can't execute any jquery "function", it s like he can t find the jquery file, BUT It works for one of my View and that s IT ?_? why !?!